# Building a DTLS server with Java (bouncycastle)

Tags: java, bouncycastle, dtls

I want to set up a (server) socket which receives DTLS connections. Is there any documentation which tells more than [this thread](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/DTLS-SRTP-with-bouncycastle-1-49-td4656286.html)?

A working example of the information provided there would be nice too.

Comment: maybe this will help https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/tls/test/DTLSServerTest.java

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Thanks, it is the first step indeed, in the thread I linked they start out with that file, but there are many-many pieces to get in place until you can accept a connection.